# Extract nonzero elements of each row of an array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm using Python 3.9/NumPy 1.22.

Suppose I have a 3x3 matrix:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[10, 40, 0],
              [0, 40, 90],
              [10, 0, 90]])
```

All elements are integers >= 0.
Every row has exactly 2 non-zero integers.

I would like to extract the nonzero integers to produce the 3x2 matrix `y` such that

```py
y = np.array([[10, 40],
              [40, 90],
              [10, 90]])
```

I feel close when using `numpy.apply_along_axis`, `numpy.squeeze`, and/or `numpy.where`, but I'm missing something.

Comment: If you want to use apply_along-axis then : `y = np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: [b for b in a if b], 1, x)`

Comment: *"All elements are integers > 0"* - Clearly not. Some are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that you have the same number of zeros per row, you can safely drop them and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape):

```
x = np.array([[10,40,0],[0,40,90],[10,0,90]])

out = x[x!=0].reshape(len(x), -1)
```

Output:

```
array([[10, 40],
       [40, 90],
       [10, 90]])
```

---

For fun, if you didn't have the same number of zeros, you could move them to the end, then slice to keep the minimum number of them:

```
x = np.array([[10,40,0],[0,40,90],[0,0,90]])
# array([[10, 40,  0],
#        [ 0, 40, 90],
#        [ 0,  0, 90]])

m = x!=0
out = np.take_along_axis(x, np.argsort(~m, axis=1),
                         axis=1)[:, :m.sum(axis=1).max()]
# array([[10, 40],
#        [40, 90],
#        [90,  0]])
```

Comment: as usual I make things hard...tx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution but it requires knowledge of the exact number of non-zero elements (in this case, 2)

```
x = np.array([[10,40,0],[0,40,90],[10,0,90]])  # exactly 2 non-zero per row
idx = np.where(x>0)
idx
Out[90]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int64))
y = x[idx].reshape((3,2))
y
Out[92]: 
array([[10, 40],
       [40, 90],
       [10, 90]])
```

Comment: Actually, you can replace `2` by `-1` to have numpy infer the value (which is what I did in my answer) ;)